# What is wrong with these @font-face fonts in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-face, embedded-fonts, webfonts

For some reason, when I view [this page](http://www.outerbox360.com/samples/DataQdirect/markup/product.html) in IE9, all of the @font-face fonts look way smaller than they should, and maybe like a different typeface too. As far as I can tell, everything about my syntax should be cooperating with IE9. Others have had trouble replicating the issue, so maybe it is something in my Windows font settings? Either way, if you want to try to replicate what I am seeing, I am running IE9 on Windows 7 64bit.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is a problem with the page, or a problem with my browser. Either way, I need to get it fixed.

Comment: well i checked in ie8 win 64bit and it looks fine

Comment: Can't reproduce in IE 9 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with some setting on my machine. I double checked that IE's font settings were default, and I tried with ClearType turned off, and back on. No luck. I don't know what other settings I would check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks the same for me in IE9 as other browsers, none are using the embedded font due to its different name (`HelveticaMD` vs the actual name in use in the CSS, `Helvetica`.)

It looks like your “wrong” screenshot is of a browser trying to actually use the embedded font, whereas the “right” screenshot is just the default font. If that's what you want, just get rid of the font embedding stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

**Usage Example:**

```
@font-face {
   font-family: MyFont;
   src: url(http://mysite/fonts/MyFont.ttf)
      format("embedded-opentype");
 }
 p {font-family: MyFont, serif;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already seen this syntax. I've tried this, as well as several other syntaxes, and nothing seems to change the issue.

Answer (score 0):

.woff solves the problem in IE9.        I've used .eot for chrome & firefox. And .woff for IE9. Now the 3 browsers are working fine and showing the same results. Following is the code in CSS.        @font-face {font-family: 'cert_fonts'; src: url('../fonts/GoudyTrajan.eot') format('eot'); src: url('../fonts/GoudyTrajan.woff') format('woff'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;}